# How many strings of length n can be constructed with 'a', 'b', and 'c', such that there is a maximum of one 'b' and two consecutive 'c's?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

I was looking at [this question](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5717453712654336):

> Given a length n, return the number of strings of length n that can be made up of the letters 'a', 'b', and 'c', where there can only be a maximum of 1 'b's and can only have up to two consecutive 'c's

For instance, given $n = 3$, the following are valid combinations:

> $$aaa,aab,aac,aba,abc,aca,acb,baa,bac,bca,caa,cab,cac,cba,cbc,acc,bcc,cca,ccb$$

Someone answering the question listed $n \cdot n + (n - 1) \cdot (n - 1) + (n + 1)$ as an answer, but I do not understand how it was derived.

Comment: is ccc valid?${}$

Comment: No, `ccc` is not valid because it has three consecutive `c`s

Comment: oh ok, but ccacc is valid?

Comment: Yea, I believe it is.

Answer (score 3):

> Don't worry, the answer $a(n):=n^2+(n-1)^2+n+1$ is simply wrong.
>
> Your enumeration of $19$ valid words of length $3$ is correct, since there is a total of $3^3=27$ words of length $3$ built from an alphabet $\mathcal{V}=\{a,b,c\}$ and there are eight bad words
>   \begin{align*}
> \{abb,bab,bba,bbb,bbc,bcb,cbb,ccc\}
> \end{align*}
>   containing more than one $b$ or more than two consecutive $c$'s and none of them is in your list of valid words. On the other hand  $a(3)=17$ which is not correct.